# Winamp "Now Playing" POST to PHP script

Tags: plugins, http, winamp

I have tried/researched 8 or so different plugins for Winamp that allow this functionality, and none of them seem to work on Windows 7 x64!

I need a plugin for Winamp that will send the current playing track information to a PHP script, via GET or POST.

I have almost no requirements... it can be the name/artist, or the filename (preferred).  No fancy functionality needed, just something basic!

The four that I actually are:

- Now Playing
- XML HTML Server
- SongStat
- Currently Hearing

Any suggestions?

*(Note to Moderators:  No, I'm not looking for "shopping recommendations", I just need a plugin that works.  There probably is only "one answer" to this question, and if there isn't, feel free to make it a CW.)*

Comment: Not really what you want, but Audioscrobbler (now part of last.fm) is similar - sends "now playing" information. Except it's an entire web2.0service, with logs and public stats and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found something that will meet my needs.  The installation process is tricky though, so I will outline it here.

What you want to get is called [AMIP](http://amip.tools-for.net/wiki/amip/features), and its primary feature is to bother people on mIRC with what you are listening to.  [Download it](http://amip.tools-for.net/wiki/amip/download), and install it with Winamp.

Next, [download their configurator](http://amip.tools-for.net/ds/dl.php?f=/files/amip_config.zip).  It is separate from the plugin.

Next, download [AMIP Dynamic Image Signature](http://amip.tools-for.net/ds/dl.php?f=/files/amipds.zip).  This is really just a config file, a copy of cURL, and a PHP script to generate forum signature tags.  Ignore the stock PHP script and write your own.  Check `$_GET` for everything you need.

Also, the config file is missing a `"` after the time in minutes:seconds.

After all this hassle, it is now working great.